# Regular Expression in Python: Find words of length n or longer

Tags: python, regex

We just learned about using regular expression in my first python course (extremely new to programming), and one of the homework problems that I am struggling with requires us to use regular expression to find all the words of length n or longer, and then use that regular expression to find the longest word used from a text file.

I have no problem when I want to test out a specific length, but it returns an empty list when I use an arbitrary variable n:

```
import re
with open('shakespeare.txt') as file:
    shakespeare = file.read()

n = 10 #if I take this out and put an actual number in the curly bracket below, it works just fine.

words = re.findall('^[A-Za-z\'\-]{n,}', shakespeare, re.M)
print(words)
len(words)
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong and how to resolve this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

For more context...
To find the longest word, I used:

```
#for word with special characters such as '-' and '''
longest_word = max(re.findall('\S+', shakespeare, re.M), key = len)

#for word without special characters:
longest_pure_word = max(re.findall('[A-Za-z]+ ', shakespeare, re.M), key = len)

output1(special char): tragical-comical-historical-pastoral
output2(pure word): honorificabilitudinitatibus
```

I didn't use n because I couldn't get the first part of the question to work.

Comment: You need to mark strings as `r''` or use double backslashes for escapes instead. Also to put the value of `n` into the string you need to format it, using `'{{{n}}}'.format(n=n)`. The extra `'{{...}}'` are required to "survive" the formatting. Or you can use `'{%d}' % n` instead.

Comment: Why would you expect `n` to be replaced by a variable's contents, but no other character in the expression to be so replaced?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
with open('shakespeare.txt') as file:
    shakespeare = file.read()

n = 10

words = re.findall('^[A-Za-z\'\-]{'+str(n)+',}', shakespeare, re.M)
print(words)
len(words)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked beautifully!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" or upvote if it helped you.